# How to make multiple roles as mainRole

Tags: javascript, mute

Here's the code:

`let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Memebers', 'Member', 'Lucid');`

This is my mute command for my Discord bot. I want to have several roles as mainRole. There are different roles in many servers, and I want the mute command to work in every server. Is there any code I need to add to make this possible. The pic shows what I mean to say by having multiple roles as mainRole. I'm using Visual Studio Code and Node.js for this. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: please do not post code as images, consider including code chunks in your question

Comment: Let me edit it, how's that? Would you help me then?